# I want to learn how to script to make an image change when clicked

Tags: image, scripting

So I'm trying to find the best tutorial on: `how I can script an image to change when its clicked on or enlarged`. The one I would use for an example I saw on `twitter` was a boy sitting in his room and when clicked on it became the boy sitting with outer space surrounding him. Now, I'm not sure if anyone has seen or know what I am referencing to, but this is the type of image im looking to make.

Anyways, the tutorials I have googled and tried to use are not really beginner types such as if you haven't used `java script` before you screwed and I'm just seeing if anyone here can give me a better idea on what I have to do.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the onclick javascript function to toggle the background of the image.  Something like the code below..

put this script in the head section of html page

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function ChangeBG()
{
    if(document.getElementById("divImg").style.backgroundImage == "url(home_image.jpg)")
    {
        document.getElementById("divImg").style.backgroundImage = "url(apparatus.gif)";
    }
    else
    {
        document.getElementById("divImg").style.backgroundImage == "url(home_image.jpg)"
    }
}
</script>
```

use this code in the body of page

```
<div id="divImg" style="background-image: url(home_image.jpg); height: 400px; width: 400px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;">
    <img alt="Admin" src="admin1.gif" onclick="ChangeBG();" />
</div>
```

Comment: I'm probably gonna sound like a complete fool, but am I doing this on Javascript or do I need to download something? Scripting and programming are my weakest points when it comes to electronics. So im at the basics of basic.

Comment: All of us were novice at a time, so do not hesitate in asking. First block of code is javascript, second block is html. You can write html pages using notepad, but I will suggest an text editor with intellisense, e.g. NotePad++ (free download). There are many sites that provide tutorials in programming. One such site is w3schools.com. My suggestion is to learn step by step, first html, then javascript.